# Raspberry wont boot using SD card prepared using dd on Ubuntu

Tags: boot, sd-card, boot-issues, windows, ubuntu

This is weird.
Raspberry Pi wont boot (red led is glowing) using SD card which image is written using dd on Ubuntu laptop, while it will boot if same SD card is written using very same image file on Windows 7 laptop.
It happened to me a year ago and yesterday again. Very frustrating...
I could not find any solution on internet.
Can someone shade some light?
Cheers!

What I'm asking is can someone clarify possible causes Raspbian image written to SD using Ubuntu `dd` tool cannot boot while when same SD card is written using ImageWriter on Windows 7 Raspberry Pi can boot from it?

Comment: Several possibilities. 1) Ubuntu copy bytes is broken, 2) you gave the wrong command, 3) the Ubuntu SD card reader hardware is broken.

Comment: thanks for fast response :)
can you elaborate your answer under bullets 1 and 3: 1) what is ubuntu copy byte and how this issue would manifest other then case I described? 3) card reader hardware seems to operate fine in all other scenarios

Comment: it might help, if you would add the complete `dd` command that you have used to write the SD card

Comment: Problems of the sort, "I put a potato in the microwave, but it did not cook it!" imply either the microwave is broken or you are not using it properly, and have no possible anwser beyond various random musings -- e.g., it could be EM interference.   It could be some kind of malware on the Ubuntu system.   The possibilities are endless.

Comment: I checked several sites for "dd" command howto before I searched for help here, one of them is: http://elinux.org/RPi_Easy_SD_Card_Setup#Flashing_the_SD_Card_using_Linux_.28including_on_a_Raspberry_Pi.21.29
I unmount both partitions (/dev/sdb1 and /dev/sdb2) and after that I applied this "dd" command `dd if=~/2012-12-16-wheezy-raspbian.img of=/dev/sdb` after which I run sync and ejected drive in unity.

Comment: The answer is **there's no reason** it should not work *unless something is broken.*

Comment: I just had this issue after i wrote the `.zip` to the SD card instead of inflating and writing the `.img` :)

Answer (score 2):

In one comment in this [post](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/31434/error-error-in-check-disks-on-openelec-reboot?noredirect=1#comment39720_31434)

> I recently tried openelec, and got the same error. Mine came from first trying to write with dd using bs=1024k. Dropping it to bs=512k resolved it for me.

Try to drop *bs* parameter.

Comment: this looks promising, but can someone explain background, why reducing `bs` parameter would fix this issue? is it something with card reader performances? what is standard value for Windows (imagewriter) because it works under windows just fine...
Many sites on internet advise this parameter to be increased to 4M (`bs=4M`) in case when Linux is used to write raspberry image to SD card...