# Can't erase SD card after installing Windows 10 IoT

Tags: pi-3, sd-card, windows-iot, pi-3b+

I tried installing Windows 10 IoT but now I want to come back to Raspbian stretch.

I mounted the sd card on my mac and tried to format the sd card to re-install the OS but my sd card became a 32MB card.

I tried to erase the card with GUI Diskutil but it wasn't working.

I've tried to format also with the terminal using this:
`sudo diskutil eraseDisk FAT32 EMPTY MBRFormat /dev/disk1`
but stuck on 50% and it never ends.

I've downloaded [SD Card Formatter](https://www.sdcard.org/downloads/formatter_4/) but it throws these errors:

```
[ERROR] Invalid end of sector signature: 0x0000
[ERROR] fat_check_validate_boot_sector returned error: 22 (Invalid argument)
[ERROR] Initializing cached values failed: 22 (Invalid argument)
[ERROR] Generated invalid volume. fat_volume_create returned: 22 (Invalid argument)
```

I'm stuck and I don't know how to re-format this card to re-install Raspbian Strech

---

#### Update:

I'm using Etcher to burn the sd card and if I use it, it says the there is not enough space.

---

#### Update 2:

I don't think it's a duplicate of the question [SD Card Showing as 30 MB on a 32 GB Card. Can't Format, Can't create a partition table](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/61895/sd-card-showing-as-30-mb-on-a-32-gb-card-cant-format-cant-create-a-partition)
as in that question, there are no error codes more he is working on Linux and not on OS X. Since I didn't tried with Linux and Windows I don't know if it is the same problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SD Card Showing as 30 MB on a 32 GB Card. Can't Format, Can't create a partition table](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/61895/sd-card-showing-as-30-mb-on-a-32-gb-card-cant-format-cant-create-a-partition)

Comment: This is a rare SD Card failure. See https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/61895/sd-card-showing-as-30-mb-on-a-32-gb-card-cant-format-cant-create-a-partition/61897#61897 A few other people have reported similar issues.

Comment: @Milliways lucky me. I will try with an Android phone, with windows and with an external camera to let you know if it is a card failure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tried to format the micro SD card with an Android phone, with Windows, and with a camera. I can definitely say that the SD card is broken and no more recoverable.

Answer (score 0):

You can use "rufus" on Window to format your SD Card, it works with me :)

Comment: Unfortunately I'm on Mac

Comment: You **DO NOT** need to format the Card to install an OS image.

Answer (score 0):

I am using Disk Utility for Mac mostly, but sometimes it does not give exact results for me. So at that point, I am using a program called SDFormatter. You might want to try. [SDFormatter](https://www.sdcard.org/downloads/formatter_4/eula_mac/index.html)

Comment: You **DO NOT** need to format the Card (on Mac or any other platform) to install an OS image.

Comment: I beleive you should make its format to FAT32. So dont you have to format it ?

Comment: The card is broken!

Answer (score 0):

Use [SDFormatter](https://www.sdcard.org/downloads/formatter_4/), it is official from the [SD Card](https://www.sdcard.org/) enterprise, it is avaliabe for Mac and Win, i had the same problem and it worked for me.

An other way to do it in Mac is using `Disk Utility` ([Disk utility on Mac page](https://support.apple.com/guide/disk-utility/welcome/mac)), it is already installed, go to `Applications/Utilities/Disk Utility`, it normally works. **Don't forget to select `exFat` or `FAT (MS-DOS)`**

Comment: **NOTE: You Will need Admin Rights fot the Both Programs**